# Saving/Serializing OkHttp/Retrofit Requests

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to be able to recover from crash/closing the app or just device being disconnected.

Currently when I detect that the network is out for my Android device I save the Call created with RetroFit2 in a stack (to process later). If the user were to close the app or restart the device I lose the possibility to save these calls anywhere...

My question is the following, how can I save a RetroFit Call or an OkHttp3 Request? 
None of them is serializable or nor can I convert them to strings from what I could see looking at the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [android priority jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) by Yigit Boyar (one of the google android guys). It'll serailize your jobs, detect network changes (and respond accordingly) and persist even through device reboots (let alone app crashes). Plus a ton of other features. Just take a look. It is not exactly what you requested but it's a better solution. It's Magic.

> Starting with v2, Job Queue can be integrated with JobScheduler or GCMNetworkManager. This integration allows Job Queue to wake up the aplication based on the criterias of the Jobs it has. You can see the deatails on the related wiki page. The Scheduler API is flexible such that you can implement a custom version of it if your target market does not have Google Play Services.

Try it and you'll be glad you did,  as I've been. It filled the huge gap in my code that I spent weeks hacking together with spit, ducktape and faith.

Comment: Thank you Elvis, I didn't see how it would recover from a app crash though, do you have any pointers as to whether it would work or not?

Comment: I recovers from app crashes and even phone reboots from my usage. What it does is that it hooks into GCMNetworkManager (Google Play Services) or framework's JobScheduler(https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) which wake up the application and thus the job manager,  executing whatever code you scheduled for execution.

Comment: Unless the Google play services and/or JobScheduler crash, and fail to restart (never gonna happen unless your phone explodes -- looking at you note 7), the scheduled task will happen.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll check it out and validate your answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct. However this does not directly address the real underlying problem which is the serialization of the POST/GET/Whatever request in itself. I have found no such solution.

Comment: This solution with JobQueue allows you to resent the request with the appropriate data. In order to be retrievable from a crashed state you need all objects that you pass to be Serializable (otherwise it throws an exception).

Comment: Yes, that happens. You can serialize unserializable objects. But there's a retry callback where you could do some checks and retry the whole job. That said, try avoiding the app crash...if possible. There's really no good way to recover from a crash to the same exact state you were in.